Baked Normal Map Artefacts

I just baked a normal map from a high poly model to a low poly model. There is a part where faces face eachother and the shading seems to be flipped? Is there something wrong with the normals on the high poly model?
Thanks.


Hello, so how does the normal map look like? Maybe you need to correct it or rebake?

@moonboots I just added the map. The problem is where the green strip is

so there was a problem with the bake somehow, maybe it's fixable with a different Extrusion value, or with a cage, or you could paint directly on the map with a correct blue color?

I think i know why this occurs. Both meshes cross each other in the problematic area.
I tested it and was able to reproduce your problem;

The area with the wrong normal direction is identical with the part of my low poly cube that is intersecting with the high poly cube.
By watching out to keep both meshes from intersecting each other, the problem was fixed:
If it isn't intentional that both meshes intersect in an area, e.g. when modeling holes, the result isn't as expected. Just make sure, the inner mesh stays inside.
Hope it helped
